# Ext.getCmp is not working in ExtJS4

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am trying to create a component and access it inside controller. But while accessing the component by id, it is not returning the component. It always returns undefined. Please find below the code.

enter code here

```
//Component creation in view layer as below

Ext.define('MyApp.view.performance.grid.IFrameGridCmp', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.crMainPanel',
    id:'mainPanelId',
    layout: {
        align: 'stretch',
        type: 'vbox'
    },
    border:0,
    resizable: false,
    forceFit: true,
    autoWidth: true,
    initComponent: function() {
        Ext.apply(this, {
            items: [
                {
                    xtype:'panel',
                    flex:.02,
                    border:0
                },
                {
                    xtype:'crHeaderPanel',
                    flex:.05
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'crUpperPanel',
                    flex: 0.93
                },
                Ext.create('Ext.Component', {
                    autoEl: {
                        tag: 'iframe', 
                        cls: 'x-hidden', 
                        src: Ext.SSL_SECURE_URL
                    },
                    id:'FileDownloader',
                    height:0,
                    listeners: {
                        afterrender: function () {
                            this.getEl().on('load', function () {
                                console.log('loaded download frame');
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    load: function(config){
                        var e = this.getEl();
                        e.dom.src = config.url + (config.params ? '?' + Ext.urlEncode(config.params) : '');
                        e.dom.onload = function() {
                            Ext.getBody().unmask();
                            if(e.dom.contentDocument.body.childNodes[0].wholeText == '404') {
                                Ext.Msg.show({
                                    title: 'Attachment missing',
                                    msg: 'The document you are after can not be found on the server.',
                                    buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,
                                    icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR 
                                });
                            }
                        };
                    }
                })
            ]
        });
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});

========================================

    enter code here

//Accessing the controller as below in controller

views: ['performance.grid.IFrameGridCmp'],

//The below line gives error
var downloader = Ext.getCmp('FileDownloader');
            downloader.load({
                url: '/APXUI/data/json/xls?exportData='+Ext.JSON.encode(records)
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, the view is not created at the time you are calling `Ext.getCmp()`

Note that `views: ['performance.grid.IFrameGridCmp'],` is only a sort of binding that view to the controller, which means the controller will create a getter for you, nothing more. You still need to instantiate the view by calling `.create();` or `Ext.widget('crMainPanel')`

Answer (score 0):

In you controller use control for example to handle it:

```
me.control({
    'crMainPanel #FileDownloader': {
         afterrender: me.addDownloader
    }
});
```

Don't use Ext.getCmp() it is really slow and you will have many issues with that. 
Don't use id - better use itemId. 
Why you need to call this from controller?

Comment: getCmp is not slow at all, in fact it's probably the fastest way to look up a component other than having a direct reference. However, I agree it's better to avoid using them in a large application.

Comment: Yes you right, about speed :) I am not use it and in my mind slow - in general. This video can describe why not need to use. http://vimeo.com/14816550

Comment: I guess @EvanTrimboli will know this as one of the core developers ;-)